# Serializar/Deserializar struct para envio via sockets

Tags: c, struct, socket

tenho uma struct que gostaria de serializar/desarializar para mandar em uma conexão via sockets usando a função [`send`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send) e recuperar essa struct com a função [`recv`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv), quais são as maneiras que posso resolver esse problema? estou atento da função [`htons`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924598/understanding-htonl-and-ntohl) mas não descobri como usa-lo efetivamente em uma `struct`.

**Struct para Serializar/Deserializar**

```c
struct header
{
    uint32_t payload_len;
    uint32_t psecret;
    uint16_t step;
    uint16_t student_id;
};

typedef struct header Cabecalho;


struct packet
{
    Cabecalho* cabecalho;
    char* msg;
};

typedef struct packet Pacote;
```

Nesse caso preciso mandar a struct `packet` para a rede.

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, sempre que trafegar pela rede estruturas como a que você mostra é preciso se preocupar com o alinhamento dos campos da estrutura. Neste caso específico
não é preciso fazer nada, mas é algo que se deve ter em mente.

```
// ------------------------------

typedef struct Header
{
  uint32_t payload_len;
  uint32_t psecret;
  uint16_t step;
  uint16_t student_id;
} Header;

typedef struct Packet
{
  Header header;
  char* msg;
} Packet;

// ------------------------------

// este e' o header que sua aplicacao vai usar localmente
Header header;

// esta e' o pacote que vai ser enviado ou recebido pela rede
Packet packet;

// ------------------------------

// no envio

packet.header.payload_len = htonl(header.paylod_len);
packet.header.psecret     = htonl(header.psecret);
packet.header.step        = htons(header.step);
packet.header.student_id  = htons(header.student_id);

n = send(fd, &packet, ....);

// ------------------------------

// na recepcao

n = recv(fd, &packet, ....);

header.paylod_len = ntohl(packet.header.payload_len);
header.psecret    = ntohl(packet.header.psecret);
header.step       = ntohs(packet.header.step);
header.student_id = ntohs(packet.header.student_id);

// ------------------------------
```